# Matching strings in reverse order in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, match

I have this file with pairs of strings separated by white space in the first column and two more columns with values.
I'd like to create a new file where the pairs of strings are matched in the same line, regardless of their order.
For example, print the line that contains pair "GAT_1 GAT_2", and the line that contains "GAT_2 GAT_1" next to it.
After assigning each of the strings to a variable for a given pair, how can I compare them for different lines without repetition?

```
# discard headers

foreach $line (@file) {
  @columns = split (/\t/, $line);
  @strings = split (/\s/, $columns[0]);
    # pseudocode:
foreach line that has pair "$strings[0] $strings[1]" {
    print $line,"\t", and $line where pair is "$strings[1] $strings[0]"

Input:
   pair         val1    val2
GAT_1 GAT_2     0.2     4.5
GAT_1 GAT_3     0.1     0.2
GAT_4 GAT_5     0.9     7.5
GAT_5 GAT_4     0.5     8.3
BLAC BABA       8.3     1.3
BABA BLAC       8.9     1.1
GAT_2 GAT_1     1.2     2.1
GAT_3 GAT_1     3.4     4.3


Ouput:
   pair        val1     val2       pair        val1   val2
GAT_1 GAT_2     0.2     4.5    GAT_2 GAT_1     1.2     2.1
GAT_1 GAT_3     0.1     0.2    GAT_3 GAT_1     3.4     4.3
GAT_4 GAT_5     0.9     7.5    GAT_5 GAT_4     0.5     8.3
BLAC BABA       8.3     1.3    BABA BLAC       8.9     1.1
```

Comment: You only care about the lines that have matching (reversed) pairs ? Also, how do you enforce a strict amount of values after splits? And of course, what's this for ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've tried very hard to solve this on your own. Pseudocode is a start, but how about an actual effort?

Comment: @sln Yes, I only care about those lines, but all of them should have a matching reversed pair.
I was trying to avoid producing a file with the following output for each match:
pair        val1     val2       pair        val1   val2
GAT_1 GAT_2     0.2     4.5    GAT_2 GAT_1     1.2     2.1
GAT_2 GAT_1     1.2     2.1    GAT_1 GAT_2     0.2     4.5
But I don't know how to enforce a strict amount of values after splits.
This is to eliminate redundancy in the file, as pairs are being treated as different entities, but they
are actually the same.

Comment: @Matt Jacob I really could not figure out an algorithm to tackle this, the question should have been "is this possible at all?"

Comment: This is programming---anything is possible! ;-) Look into hashes specifically. How big is your input file?

Comment: I thought about hashes, but the only thing linking the lines I want to match isn't exactly the same (because its reversed), so it could not work as the key. The input file is about 100000 lines long.

Comment: What if you reversed it and then checked, or just stored everything in a normalized form?

Comment: Yes, get everything into the same form first, then sort. Are you working under Windows or Unix/linux?

Comment: How can I reverse just half of it? Because if I reverse everything I'll be exactly where I am right now. What do you mean by "normalized form"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to approach this problem, and it'll work for an arbitrary number of columns of values. The basic approach is what I suggested in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187313/matching-strings-in-reverse-order-in-perl#comment56124144_34187313), which is to normalize the key and then push any values we find onto an array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %unique;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /^\S/;
    my @fields = split;

    my $key = join(' ', sort(splice(@fields, 0, 2)));
    push(@{$unique{$key}}, @fields);
}

for my $key (keys(%unique)) {
    print join("\t", $key, @{$unique{$key}});
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
   pair         val1    val2
GAT_1 GAT_2     0.2     4.5
GAT_1 GAT_3     0.1     0.2
GAT_4 GAT_5     0.9     7.5
GAT_5 GAT_4     0.5     8.3
BLAC BABA       8.3     1.3
BABA BLAC       8.9     1.1
GAT_2 GAT_1     1.2     2.1
GAT_3 GAT_1     3.4     4.3
```

Output:

```
GAT_4 GAT_5     0.9     7.5     0.5     8.3
GAT_1 GAT_2     0.2     4.5     1.2     2.1
BABA BLAC       8.3     1.3     8.9     1.1
GAT_1 GAT_3     0.1     0.2     3.4     4.3
```

Comment: I see what you mean by "normalize" now. It was "splice" I could not figure out on my own. Thanks.
Why do you need "next unless /^\S/;"?

Comment: The `next unless ...` line skips lines that have leading whitespace, which ignores the header row. You could also do `next if $. == 1` to explicitly skip the first line.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score -2):

Little change in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34189380/103780 will give you what you want:
(Untested):

`my @keys = splice(@fields, 0, 2);
my $key = join(' ', @keys);
my $skey = join (' ', sort @keys);
push(@{$unique{$skey}{$key}}, @fields);`

`for my $skey (keys(%unique)) {
    for my $key (keys(%unique{$skey})) {
       print join("\t", $key, @{$unique{$skey}{$key}});
       print "\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}`